# Передать значение переменной из JS в <script> код на HTML странице

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, переменные

Уже пару часов лажу по интернету и не могу решить проблему.

Пишу код в Node.js
У меня есть JS файл где обьявлена переменная color.
Второй файл это HTML страница. И мне надо в script написать

```
alert('У вас цвет ' + color);
```

Пробовал писать export в Js - возвращает ошибку, require в HTML  - возвращает ошибку.

Код js-файла:

```
var colors = ['Black', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Gold', 'Turquoise', 'Emerald'];
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
var color = colors[number];
```

Код html-файла

```
<script>
      alert('У вас цвет - ' + color)
</script>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: повесьте на window

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Можно пример?

Comment: `window.someVar = 123` в скрипте и `var value=window.someVar`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в консоле показывает ошибку на window (Пишу на node.js)

Comment: прикольно, а причем тогда Html?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в Node пишу сайт. Если хотите могу скинуть всё на google диск и в комментариях написать какую переменную куда надо передать

Comment: в конце js файла - console.log(color);  Что покажет?

Comment: @НиколайГабараев Показывает рандомное значение из массива

Comment: как подключен js-файл к html?

Comment: @НиколайГабараев Это сайт, где сам сервер запускается в index.js и там же вычисляется какой цвет будет. Потом идёт переход на /index.html и там нужно использовать эту переменную, какая генерируется рандомно при заходе в браузер.

Comment: Ну тогда если сервер сам выполняет скрипт и сам получает значение color, то он должен получается менять страницу index.html перед запуском, вставляя туда color

Comment: Используйте AJAX для этого, сделайте GET запрос на сервер. Ну или используйте какой-нибудь шаблонизатор, например [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

Comment: ну да, присоединяюсь к Степану, либо запросом, либо в момент составления html запишите вместо color Ваше значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте код с вашими переменными в тег `script`:

```
<script>
    let colors = ['Black', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Gold', 'Turquoise', 'Emerald'];
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
    let color = colors[number];
    alert('У вас цвет - ' + color);
</script>
```

и при перезагрузке страницы переменная `color` будет менять значения.
Либо если вам необходимо работать со значениями переменных в будущем вы можете создать в вашем `js`-файле функцию, возвращающую значение `color`, поместить файл в тег `script` перед кодом на ваше странице и вместо значения переменной вызывать функцию:

```
<script src="ваш_файл_скрипта.js"></script>
<script>alert('У вас цвет - ' + getColor());</script>
```

где ваш файл будет находиться в одном каталоге с `html`-файлом и иметь вид:

```
function getColor() {
        let colors = ['Black', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Gold', 'Turquoise', 'Emerald'];
        let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
        let color = colors[number];
        return color;
}
```